# wordpress update category function

Tags: php, wordpress

I am looking for a function that will fire a php file when a category is updated. I don't really want to use a plugin, just want a function to go in functions.php. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

Seems there was a function called "edited_category" but this seems to have been renamed to edited_{$taxonomy} .But I can find no documentation on how to use this. Anyone got any Ideas?

Comment: In case no one answers: there seems to be a hook: http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/edit_%7B$taxonomy%7D How to use hooks: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [edit_category hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Post.2C_Page.2C_Attachment.2C_and_Category_Actions_.28Admin.29)

> Runs when a category is updated/edited, including when a post or
>   blogroll link is added/deleted or its categories are updated (which
>   causes the count for the category to update). Action function
>   arguments: category ID.

You can add the hook in your `functions.php` file as given below

```
add_action ( 'edited_category', 'update_category_function');
function update_category_function( $category_id )
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: sorry about the delay mad day! i can't get this to work seems (I think) this function has be renamed to edited_{$taxonomy} but I can find no documentation on how to use this. Any Ideas?